# Why is my FBX export incorrect/faulty, when exporting deform bones only from blender

Tags: export, .fbx, rigify

i have a rigged character, that i want to export as FBX (mesh and deform bones) and put in mixamo for animations, and later bind the animation to character in blender.

But, when i export my model to FBX from blender, it does not import to mixamo (error- "unable to map existing skeleton"). When i import the just exported FBX in blender itself, i can see that there are few extra bones in the FBX (FK bones) and scale of head bone is also incorrect. Perhaps this is the reason why mixamo is unable to import it.

Please help as to why the FBX export from blender behaving like this and how an i solve it. THanks.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Mixamo has its own naming conventions and bones hierarchy and orientations that have to be respected in order to work.

So the common workfolw is to let Mixamo rig the character with its own auto rig algorithm, save as fbx and import in Blender.

When imported in Blender you have three main options:

1. use it as it is (pure FK)
2. build a better rig around it (Useful addons: Mixamo rig Addon or Mixamo to Rigify Addon)
3. Retarget the animation from Mixamo Rig to your own rig (useful addons: Auto Rig Pro or Retargeter Helper Addon).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have tried retargeting from mixamo to my own rig. But there is something wrong. One thing is that the person who rigged my character did the body through rigify and face through Auto rig pro. So my original rigged model is bit of a mess that ways. But he has weight painted it well, so the deformation is better than what mixamo gives. So, i wanted to use the animation from mixamo with my properly weight painted rig. But its not happening. When using retargeting addons, the result is very messy